# Camel 'OUT' message not populting from 'IN' in Processor

Tags: java, apache-camel

Trying to figure out how to propagate the body from my IN message to my OUT in a processor.  See below.  Note that I'm using streamcaching and my original input is a stream.

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    log.debug("In msg:"  + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    log.debug("Out msg:"  + exchange.getOut().getBody(String.class));

    exchange.setOut(exchange.getIn());

    log.debug("In msg:"  + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    log.debug("Out msg:"  + exchange.getOut().getBody(String.class));
}
```

The output is:

```
In msg: "My Payload"
Out msg: null
In msg: (empty string)
Out msg: (empty string)
```

What I expect is:

```
In msg: "My Payload"
Out msg: null
In msg: "My Payload"
Out msg: "My Payload"
```

Where's that empty string coming from?

Comment: Read the javadoc, of getOut() and see this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Comment: As always, thanks Claus.  After some digging I think more specifically my question is different; I've created another ticket and answer this one using your comment.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/27403716/295797

Answer (score 2):

Per Claus' comment which references the [docs](http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html):

> Consider using getIn() As shown above you most often need to alter the
>   existing IN message, than creating a totally new OUT message. And
>   therefore it's often easier just to adjust the IN message directly.

Answer (score 2):

just try

```
 exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody());
```

instead of : 
       exchange.setOut(exchange.getIn());

Comment: But getOut() is deprecated in camel 2.25. Any alternate?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the same code in local and its working as expected below.

In msg: "My Payload"
Out msg: null
In msg: "My Payload"
Out msg: "My Payload"
.

I am not getting any "empty string" in the console.