# Camel - Stream cache not caching / can't convert?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I seem to be losing my 'in' body after reading it once.  Note that I am using Camel's stream caching, and that the input is a json file from the http component.   I have a processor with the following code.

```
    log.debug("Body Type: " + exchange.getIn().getBody().getClass().getCanonicalName());
    log.debug("In msg1:"  + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    log.debug("In msg2:"  + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
```

What I'd expect to see here is that msg1 and msg2 are the same output, However msg2 returns a blank string (not null).  Here are the logs at TRACE level.

```
1- DEBUG com.mycompany.MyProcessor : Body Type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache
2- TRACE org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter : Converting org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@780a5cef
3- TRACE org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter : Using converter: StaticMethodTypeConverter: public static java.lang.String org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter.toString(java.io.InputStream,org.apache.camel.Exchange) throws java.io.IOException to convert [class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache=>class java.lang.String]
4- DEBUG com.mycompany.MyProcessor : In msg1:{myJson}
5- TRACE org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter : Converting org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache -> java.lang.String with value: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@780a5cef
6- TRACE org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter : Using converter: StaticMethodTypeConverter: public static java.lang.String org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter.toString(java.io.InputStream,org.apache.camel.Exchange) throws java.io.IOException to convert [class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache=>class java.lang.String]
7- DEBUG com.mycompany.MyProcessor : In msg2:
```

Things to note from the logs:

- Line 1- The Body Type is correctly showing a cached input stream
- Line 4- Converting to String *does work* to produce msg1, even though line 3, the conversion code, seems to fail with an IOException
- Line 6- Also failing the conversion but it's important to note that the body is still a cached stream.
- Line 7- My message is lost.

So where did msg2 go?

**EDIT**

Some things to mention in addition to Peter's answer below:

Camel's MessageHelper static class has two useful functions:

- `resetStreamCache`
- `extractBodyAsString`

Both of which will help for this situation

Comment: Please show us how you set up the stream cache.

Comment: We have this code to reset the stream (in scala)    ----     object StreamResetter extends Processor {
  import org.apache.camel.util.MessageHelper
  import org.apache.camel.Exchange

  override def process(exchange: Exchange): Unit = MessageHelper.resetStreamCache(exchange.getIn)
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using stream cache allows you to read streams *more than once in different* processors but still *only once in the same processor*.

I tested with:

```
ModelCamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
context.setStreamCaching(true); //!!
// ...

from("direct:start")
    .to("http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=showMyIP")
    .process(new MyProcessor())
    .process(new MyProcessor());
```

And:

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpStreamCache.MyProcessor.class);
    @Override
    public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("***** Body Type: " + exchange.getIn().getBody().getClass().getCanonicalName());
        LOG.info("***** In msg1  : " + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
        LOG.info("***** In msg2  : " + exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    }
};
```

This prints:

```
INFO  ***** Body Type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache
INFO  ***** In msg1  : showMyIP({"ip": "00.000.000.00"});

INFO  ***** In msg2  : 
INFO  ***** Body Type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache
INFO  ***** In msg1  : showMyIP({"ip": "00.000.000.00"});

INFO  ***** In msg2  :
```

Comment: That's interesting ..  Was that something you found out through investigation or is it documented?

Comment: @Peter Keller  Is there anyway to access data multiple times within same processor ?
And actually for the above case to get  body in two different processors I don't even need streamCache = true ...right?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you problem is not the input stream is gone, but rather that it's reader position is at the last point of consumption, in this case, at the end of the stream.

you could use a stream "rewind" method that could bring your reader to the beginning of the stream - only if the stream supports it.

Here's a scala code that provides such a resetter:

```
object StreamResetter extends Processor {
  import org.apache.camel.util.MessageHelper
  import org.apache.camel.Exchange

  override def process(exchange: Exchange): Unit = MessageHelper.resetStreamCache(exchange.getIn)
}
```

than, on your route, just before the second log call, you can use

```
process(StreamResetter)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Working example for me:

```
from("direct:secondRoute")
     .to("callOtherService")
     .log("RESPONSE: ${body}")  
     .process(exchange -> {
        InputStream in = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);
        in.reset();
     });

from("direct:firstRoute")
     .to(direct:secondRoute)
     .convertBodyTo(String.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

If using spring boot, just enable stream caching.

```
camel.springboot.stream-caching-enabled=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content of your JSON input stream is not prohibitively large, you could convert your input stream into `ByteArrayInputStream` and that way you can read from it multiple times in any `Processor`. Hope that helps.